# speeding up std::map and boost:unordered_map [] operation

Tags: c++, stl, dictionary

I have a MAP which is optionally of type std::map and optionally of type unordered_map ( according to typdef MAP)  , and a function which adds a value to the given keyed value:

```
  func1(MAP<string,  double>  &map, string  &key, double &val2add){
    try
{
      map.at(key)  += val2add;
}catch(out_of_range& oor){
          map[key] = val2add; // in case map[key] didn't exist before. 
    }
  }
```

The problem is that this means double ( and possibly even more ) work than simply

```
  func2(MAP<string,  double>  &map, string  &key, double &val2add){
       map[key] += val2add; // if map[key] doesn't exist - problem
  }
```

But the above would not work, since as i understand the [] operator initializes a new object in map with the defined key, and with the default double value. If i knew that the default double value is 0, then func2 would still achieve what i want it to - but i can't rely on that.

So is there any way to use [] in a better way over func1?

Comment: I'm not understanding what your problem is. `operator[]` for both `std::map` and `std::unordered_map` is guaranteed to create an entry for the key with a value-initialized value, if the key doesn't already exist. Every basic type value-initializes to 0.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no problem with your second piece of code. If the key is not found, then `[]` will insert a value-initialised object (in this case, a `double` with value zero), and return a reference to that. So, in that case `map[key] += value` has the same effect as `map[key] = value`.

More generally, it's almost certainly more efficient to call `find` and then check the result, than to call `at` and catch the exception. Exception handling implementations often assume that exceptions are only thrown in exceptional circumstances, and optimise the usual case at the cost of the unusual.

Of course, it speed is important, then you'll need to measure it to be sure.

Comment: i thought i can't rely on default int,double values? am i wrong?

Comment: @dan12345 The default value for double is 0.0, so that's what you want. (That is very different from uninitialized variables, which you indeed cannot rely on)

Comment: @dan12345: You can usually rely on standard containers to insert value-initialised, rather than uninitialised, values. Certainly, the definition of `operator[]` specifies "If there is no key equivalent to `x` in the map, inserts `value_type(x, T())` into the map."

Answer (score 2):

You can't do it with `operator[]`, but you can use `insert` method: it returns the iterator and a bool indicating whether the returned iterator points to a previously existing element or a newly inserted element.

Also, primitive types are default-initialized to zero.

Comment: No, primitive types are *value*-initialised to zero. Default initialisation leaves them uninitialised.